# Avoid unexpected crash while using left view and right view in slide concept in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, slide

I am using both left slide and right slide menu in my app. what is my problem is i have some options in right slide view, in left slide view i have menu, center view i have some option choose buttons to call right view which have options to chose, when i call left slide view if i accidentally  press any button in center view it is calling center view to move left side and left view becoming right view even some crash occurring. so my question is how i can disable center view button action while i am in left side view or any library project there to handle this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: make use of this `@property(nonatomic, getter=isUserInteractionEnabled) BOOL userInteractionEnabled` of center view to disable its userinteraction while you are in left or right menu view..

Comment: when and where it should be given? could u more clear?

Comment: when ever you tap a button to move to left side view, call this `centerViewButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO` and whenever you come back to your center View set userinteraction to YES again.

Comment: k bala i ll try out and will say you thanks

Comment: thanks for the good time it is working!!